# Importing Jinja2 fails with Google App Engine Testbed

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

Importing Jinja2 fails when I run unit tests with the Google App Engine Testbed.

`import jinja2`

I see this error:

**ImportError: No module named jinja2**

My Yaml file looks like:

`libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest`

What is the process for the unit tests to find libraries specified by the yaml file, such as jinja2?

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing quotation marks around the version.

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "latest"
- name: jinja2
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: Thank you . I intend to test, but I put it on the back-burner because the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Configuring_libraries) do not agree with your suggestion.

Comment: @cyrf Well, I'd like you to take a look at these docs. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en